# Rails - Restrict users from following themselves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I have a following system and I would like to restrict the users controller action 'follow' if the `params[:id]` is the same as the current user.

I use cancancan (an up to date cancan gem) to do my authorizations work.

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def follow
  Followership.create(leader_id: params[:id], follower_id: current_user.id)
  ...
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers, :class_name => 'Followership', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_by, :class_name => 'Followership', dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

**models/followership.rb**

```
class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User'
  ...
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can't you just do `if params[:id] == current_user then Followership.create(...) end`?

Comment: Just to have a clean code I guess. But I did like this for the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a validation on your `Followship` model:

```
class Followership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :leader, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User'

  validate :doesnt_follow_self

  private

  def doesnt_follow_self
    errors.add(:base, 'You can\'t follow yourself') if leader == follower
  end
end
```

Comment: I was to focus on cancan, I didn't think about it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a validation:

```
#app/models/followership.rb
Class FollowerShip < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  ...
  validates_with FollowValidator
end

#app/validators/follow_validator.rb
class FollowValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.leader_id == record.follower_id
      record.errors[:leader_id] << "Sorry, you can't follow yourself!"
    end
  end
end
```

---

I was half-way through writing this when `@BroiStatse` posted